# How to force numeric evaluation?

Tags: evaluation, numerics

I need to evaluate the `PolyLog` function at some points, but I'm interested in numeric values. E.g. `PolyLog[3, 2.7]` works fine, but `PolyLog[3, e]` just prints the same `PolyLog[3, e]`. I somehow need to convert this symbolic representation to a number. Seems like a simple question, but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
N@PolyLog[3,e] or N[PolyLog[3,e]]
```

Also if by e you mean `E` or `Exp[1]` (Mathematica's notation), then you'll have to change that.

Comment: Thanks! N[] worked perfectly for me!